# c - curl socket hangs

Tags: c, sockets, curl, freeze

## Context

Debian 64bits
Learning http

## Problem

I use curl to connect to localhost port 36000 this way
curl localhost:36000 -v

I copy pasted the code here 
[non blocking socket](https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/)

Here is my replacement for the else :

```
    else
    {
        int done = 0;

        while ( 1 )
        {
            printf("yy %d\n",i);
            ssize_t count;
            char buf[210] = {0};
            /* it will block here at the second iteration */
            count = read ( events[i].data.fd, buf, sizeof buf );
            printf("count = %d\n",count);
            if ( count == -1 )
            {
                /* If errno == EAGAIN, that means we have read all
                   data. So go back to the main loop. */
                if ( errno != EAGAIN )
                {
                    perror ( "fini\n" );
                }
                break;
            }
            else if ( count == 0 )
            {
                    /* End of file. The remote has closed the
                       connection. */
                done = 1;
                break;
            }
            printf("buf ? %s\n\n\n\n",buf);

            char resp[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 103\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body>you</body></html>\n";
            printf("buf2 ? %s\n",resp);
            sentinel = write ( events[i].data.fd, resp, strlen ( resp ) + 1);


            if ( sentinel == -1 )
            {
                printf("err\n");
                //exit ( 1 );
            }

        }
        if ( done )
        {
                /* Closing the descriptor will make epoll remove it
                   from the set of descriptors which are monitored. */
            printf("out\n");
            close ( events[i].data.fd );
        }
    }
}
```

## Question

The problem is that curl hangs, and the server waits before the read at the second iteration.

I mean it reads once then write resp to the fd, then back again at the top of the while but stops at the count = read... whereas it is non blocking (!!!)

Hence the connection never closes.

Could you tell me why please ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok it was the make non blocking messing it all out. copy pasted the code and it works.

Thanks